# Wiggle Bones Addon, Bones assigned as wiggle are not physics simulated

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, physics, rigid-body-simulation

So as I work through my hair rigging, the latest bones i added and assigned wiggling to didn't get simulated. They just move as they would without the addon. The previous ones, though work fine.

[Here is a link to the file](https://dropmefiles.com/lGAq9)

Please Help!

[image]

Comment: I dont thing anyone can answer without your file, especially when other bones works for you. Delete all, keep only problematic bones, that still produce issue. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Added the file.

Comment: I asked you to clean up your file before share from several reasons ... make file lighter (people doesnt want download big  data) ... it makes easier to analyze your file (we see your blend for the first time and it is hard all relations and what is important and what should work and what is as intended) ... and sometimes you can discover issue by your-self when deleting some parts ... just suggestions to attract more people here.

Comment: Yeah, excuse my hurry, I was really busy at the time cz it was a deadline project.